# Export Jprofiler heap dump

Tags: java, jprofiler

i currently have a Jprofiler 'heapdump' file that contains a lot of valuable data which I need to export so it can be interpreted programatically..

Please see below:
[image: a busy cat]

I need to somehow get all these values out.. I have noticed theirs an export button but it only exports the items that are not collapsed.. There are over 1,000 items in here so uncollapsing them all would be unreasonable to do.

Is there any way I can do this?

Kind regards

Comment: Please insert the image directly into you post. There is no need for a external link...

Answer (score 0):

As of 9.1, there is no way to export all objects in the heap walker. Also, expanding all items would be problematic, since the references could well span the entire heap.

Comment: Would that mean that it's possible to do so in an earlier version? Or are there any other memory analyzers that would make this possible as the heap dump file I have is a .hprof format.

Comment: HPROF is just that, an export of the entire heap. What kind of export format do you need, a visual one or one that you can use for further processing?

Comment: I would need a visual one, one that could break down arrays with values for processing, so something similar to 

     array[10] {  array_value[0] { 
                                             class_fields[] { name: "a field value", id: 0}
                      }
                      }

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with JProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can save heap dump to your computer (.hprof) file it through the JProfiler 10.0 UI. (Have not used lower versions, may be a similar option exists there)
This file can then be analysed using JProfiler and Eclipse MAT (memory analyzer).

[image: Save Heap Dump (yourDump.hprof) on JProfiler 10.0]